# Scala - import is treated as an error

Tags: scala, import

I have the following project structure:

```
+ org
 \
  + dynamics
  |\
  | = RuleGradient.scala
  |
  + world
   \
    = World.scala
```

The RuleGradient file contains the class and the object RuleGradient. The World class wants to create objects of RuleGradient class, but the class is not imported correctly. Here is the import statement of the World class (proposed by the IDE itself and I agree with it):

```
import org.dynamics.RuleGradient
```

and it is also treated as an error. The IDE says:

```
- RuleGradient is not a member of org.dynamics
- RuleGradient is not a member of org.dynamics{org.dynamics.type}
```

no other imports or anything else shadows anything. Why does not the importing occure correctly? What is strange - all other classes that have the same importing architecture are imported fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that the file `RuleGradient.scala` starts with the line:

```
package org.dynamics
```

Comment: How did you even guess this? :-)

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral Because I did the same mistake in my first Java code  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Impossible to say for sure without seeing your code, but I'd guess you haven't defined the `RuleGradient` class directly in the `org.dynamics` package, but for example as in inner class of `object` instead. The name suggested by your IDE is that of the companion object, not the class.